# Select column on joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to select columns from table1 and table 2 but I can't select them:

```
SELECT table1._____
    ,table2.____
    FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.END_DATE_FW
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW 
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.LOCATION_CODE_FW 
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.COMPANY_CODE_FW 
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_RECORD_NUMBER_FW
    FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
    WHERE ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW = (SELECT MAX( ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW)
             FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
             WHERE ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW IN
                    (SELECT VEHICLE_ID_FW FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW WHERE VEHICLE_ID_FW = ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW)
             AND ALLOCATIONS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%
             )
    AND ALLOCATIONS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%
    ) AS table1
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.END_DATE_FW
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW 
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.LOCATION_CODE_FW 
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.COMPANY_CODE_FW
    ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.DRIVER_NAME_FW 
    FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
    WHERE VEHICLE_ID_FW=(SELECT VEHICLE_ID_FW FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW 
                            WHERE ALLOCATIONS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%)
    AND END_DATE_FW = (SELECT MAX( ALLOCATIONS_FW.END_DATE_FW)
             FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
             WHERE VEHICLE_ID_FW=ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW)

    ORDER BY ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW DESC
    ) AS OLDALLOC
    ON table1.column1=table2.column1
```

I want to select table1 and table2 columns how will I do it?? Because I tried the

```
table1.VEHICLE_ID_FW
table1.ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW
```

both are not working

Comment: 1. What do you mean by that it does not work? 2. You do not have table2 in your query, the second derived table's alias is oldalloc.

Comment: your second derived table alias isn't `table2`, it's `OLDALLOC` perhaps that's the problem

Comment: on my select above... I have to get the values from table1.  when I tried to use SELECT table1._____ the columns from the table1 is not appearing

Comment: a multi - part identifier problem...

Comment: Can you try giving them alias. Like: FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW AS VEHICLE_ID_FW,

Comment: The answer lies in your question. you are using "table1.`column1`=table2.column1". Ask yourself what is `column1`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, You should not use an order by clause inside a subquery. I just commented. Please try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.END_DATE_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.LOCATION_CODE_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.COMPANY_CODE_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_RECORD_NUMBER_FW
    FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
    WHERE ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW = (
            SELECT MAX(ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW)
            FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
            WHERE ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW IN (
                    SELECT VEHICLE_ID_FW
                    FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
                    WHERE VEHICLE_ID_FW = ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW
                    )
                AND ALLOCATIONS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW = % RECORD_NUMBER_FW %
            )
        AND ALLOCATIONS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW = % RECORD_NUMBER_FW %
    ) AS table1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.END_DATE_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.LOCATION_CODE_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.COMPANY_CODE_FW
        ,ALLOCATIONS_FW.DRIVER_NAME_FW
    FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
    WHERE VEHICLE_ID_FW = (
            SELECT VEHICLE_ID_FW
            FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
            WHERE ALLOCATIONS_FW.RECORD_NUMBER_FW = % RECORD_NUMBER_FW %
            )
        AND END_DATE_FW = (
            SELECT MAX(ALLOCATIONS_FW.END_DATE_FW)
            FROM ALLOCATIONS_FW
            WHERE VEHICLE_ID_FW = ALLOCATIONS_FW.VEHICLE_ID_FW
            )
    --ORDER BY ALLOCATIONS_FW.START_DATE_FW DESC
    ) AS OLDALLOC ON table1.column1 = table2.column1
```

Comment: Please try this and let me know your results. I am not able to understand why you used top 1.